# Passing scoped slots through multiple components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have 2 components.  One is a list component (list.vue).  The other takes a list and wraps it with other features(searchandlist).  Now, from the page.vue file I would like to call SearchAndList, giving it the list, and the render props.  However, I cant get the dynamic data to show, only static.

ListItems.vue

```
<span>
 <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
 <slot v-bind="item"></slot>
</div>
```

SearchAndList.vue

```
<div class="clients-list">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
        <list-items :items="items">
            <slot name="row"></slot>
        </list-items>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

page.vue

```
    <template>
<search-and-list :items="items">
  <tr slot="row">
    Hi
  </tr>
</search-and-list>

</template>

<script>
import SearchAndList from '../components/base/SearchAndList'


export default {
  components: {
    SearchAndList
  },
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: 10, name: 'Marc' },
        { id: 11, name: 'Bob' },
        { id: 12, name: 'George' }
      ]
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

When using this, I get Hi listed out 3 times as exprected.  However, when changing this to:

```
<search-and-list :items="items">
 <tr slot="row" slot-scope="item">
  {{ item.name}}
 </tr>
</search-and-list>
```

I do get "Duplicate presence of slot "default" found in the same render tree - this will likely cause render errors." in the console, however, even giving the default slot a name=list, the error is the same, but default is not list.

Im sure there is something simple that I am missing.  Any guidance would be great.

EDIT:

I have a child component () that exposes an { item } to its parent ().  However, I would like to access { item } in the grand-parent (page.vue).

Comment: Can you add the complete listings for your components? I can't quite make out what you are trying to do here. Is `list-items` the same as List.vue?

Comment: @Bert Yes, sorry I can see how this could be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 missing bit in your configuration.

Expose you item in the `List.vue`:

```
<span>
   <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
   <slot :item="item"></slot>
</div>
```

Then you need to bind the name in your `SearchAndList.vue`.

So try:

```
<div class="clients-list">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <list-items :items="items">
        <slot scope-slot="{ item }" :name="item.name"></slot>
    </list-items>
  </table>
</div>
```